# The distance from the hyperplane to the points

Tags: machine-learning, svm

In Support Vector Machines, the distance from the hyperplane to each class of nearest points should have the same length.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

The points closest to the hyperplane from each class are called support vectors. The hyperplane is halfway between support vectors from two different classes. Yes, you are correct.